# update and delete syntax in lua program

Tags: sqlite, lua, coronasdk

I am getting nil value when I tried to update the data for below code :

```
    local update_statement =db:prepare[[ UPDATE list SET :name :icon WHERE :id]]

    update_statement:bind_names{  name = aName,   icon = aIcon,  id = aId }

    update_statement:step()

    update_statement:reset()
```

And also I need the syntax for delete operation in lua program.

Please help me

Thank you,
Madan mohan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn [SQL's syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html).

Basically, you're not telling which columns you want to update, you're only giving their values.

```
local update_statement = db:prepare[[ UPDATE list SET name = :name, icon = :icon WHERE id = :id]]
```

Here's the syntax for the DELETE statement:

```
local delete_statement = db:prepare[[ DELETE FROM list WHERE id = :id]]
```